# lower and upper_bound on sorted vector of struct

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Say for example I have:

```
 struct my_stuff{
     long my_value;

     struct less_than{
           bool operator()(const my_stuff &a, const my_stuff &b){
                   return a.my_value < b.my_value;
     };
 };
```

In my code I have:

```
  vector<my_stuff> my_vec;
```

This vector already contains all the objects that I'm interested in. I then sorted my vector based on the my_value member variable

```
  sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), my_stuff::less_than());
```

Everything is fine so far. Now my vector of objects with the member variable "my_value" is now sorted based on the value of "my_value".

**My question/problem is: How do I get the lower_bound and upper_bound of this vector based on "my_value". For example, if I was given that I want all the objects in the range [low, high] of my_value, I would want my lower_bound to point to the lowest object in that bound(low) and my upper_bound to point to my high.**

What I've tried so far is...

```
 auto low = lower_bound(myvec.begin()->my_value, my_vec.end()->my_value, val);
```

And same thing for upper bound except with "upper_bound" instead of "lower_bound". How do I syntatically achieve this? What I'm trying to do after I have sorted my vector of objects is to be able to find all the objects within a certain range. I believe lower_bound and upper_bound is the correct way to go about this, but I'm stumped on writing it. Thank you for any help or guidance!

Comment: just a remark: you can get rid of `struct less_than` and instead implement the less-than operator in `my_stuff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. You could construct an instance of `my_stuff` wrapping a desired value, and pass that to `lower_bound`:

```
my_stuff test; test.my_value = val;
auto low = std::lower_bound(time_table.begin(), time_table.end(), test, 
                            my_stuff::less_than());
```

Or, add a couple of overloads to `less_than::operator()`, taking `my_stuff` on one side and `long` on the other. With a comparator that supports heterogeneous comparisons, you can write

```
auto low = std::lower_bound(time_table.begin(), time_table.end(), val,
                            my_stuff::less_than());
```

You can further avoid having to pass `my_stuff::less_than()` to `std::lower_bound` (and to `std::sort`, for that matter) if, instead of a separate comparator, you implement `my_stuff::operator<()` (you can have three overloads of that).